# Importance of Urysohn Metrization Theorem

Tags: general-topology

I was just wondering if there are good examples that stem from the Urysohn Metrization Theorem.

Are there any concrete examples that we use in Calculus or Analysis that stem from the result?  I just learned the theorem, and I wanted to know about the importance of it possibly in our daily math courses.

Thanks,
A curious student

Comment: I doubt this theorem will be of use in standard Calculus or Real Analysis course since here you are working with $\mathbb R$ or subspaces of $\mathbb R$ (which are also metrizable).  I would look in Functional Analysis possibly for applications that are not strictly topological.

Answer (score 2):

As Forever Mozart mentioned, the answer to your question is "NO" *in the strict sense*. Namely, in "standard" calculus, real analysis, or even complex analysis, the Urysohn metrization theorem is of very limited use, mainly because the underlying topological spaces in these subjects are Euclidean spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$, hence are already metrizable.

However, if we take just a little step forward to the theories of manifolds (there is a lot of calculus on manifolds!), then an immediate consequence of Urysohn metrization theorem is that

> **Corollary.** Every second-countable manifold is metrizable.

Recall that a (topological) manifold is a Hausdorff topological space $X$ where every $x\in X$ has a neighborhood $U$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for a fixed $n$). Hence, any manifold is automatically regular. In fact, a lot of authors require a manifold to be second countable.